# How to run a function after html has updated in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a server call, which is called on `ngOnInit`. I have a field called `urlLinks`, which is updated when the server call returns successfully. This updates the HTML and adds `focusable` class on the links based on the return values and other data (some have that class, and others don't).

I need to find elements that are focusable `const titleElements = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.focusable');`

```
this.urlLinks?.subscribe(data => {
      this.links = data;
      this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.focusable')//  <--- this one returns null, 
// because template hasn't rendered yet?
```

How do I know when the HTML has finished updating and is ready for class queries?

Comment: Have you tried in the lifecycle ngAfterViewInit ? I think it"s a good way to handle that,link to the doc: https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Comment: That only runs after initial init, not after the HTML is updated on later server calls, right? At least that's what's happening on my local.

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry to missunderstood your question. Maybe try to consider investigate ngAfterViewChecked, this lifecycle is render each time change detector has completed checking a component's view. Maybe have you a fiddle demo or something ?